# Microsoft SQL Server : splitting data and cross join - counter table - stuck

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using Microsoft  SQL. 
First thing let me explain that the "splitter" command in this SQL script works when my data comes in without all the cn's and paths and xml data. If the data comes in as

```
testrole|testrole2|testrole3
```

I am trying to get it to work while bringing the data in raw. It will still come in pipe delimited but with a lot more string data after the role/ access name..So I can use it later for scripting in bulk.

I want the end result to be user ID - Role and also show duplicate user IDs for users with more than one role.

1 - TestRole

2 - TestRole

2 - TestApp

3 - TestApp

Any ideas on how to get this to work? You can see some users will have one role and other multiple.

```
if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#RolesStage2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #RolesStage2

DECLARE @CountTable TABLE (UserID BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @CountTable
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)

DECLARE @TempUserObjects TABLE 
                         (
                             UserID BIGINT, 
                             AssignedRoles NVARCHAR(MAX)
                         )

INSERT INTO @TempUserObjects (UserID, AssignedRoles)
VALUES 
    (1, 'cn=TestingApp1,cn=Application,cn=Base,cn=Level2,cn=Definitions,cn=Configuration,cn=Drivers,cn=UserApplication,cn=FakePath,<assignment><start_tm>123456789575</start_tm><req_tm>1234568789854</req_tm><req>cn=FakeAdmin,ou=Admin,ou=ESC,o=authorizationpathfake</req><req_desc>Import - Child Request</req_desc></assignment>|'),
    (2, 'cn=TestingApp2,cn=Application,cn=Base,cn=Level2,cn=Definitions,cn=Configuration,cn=Drivers,cn=UserApplication,cn=FakePath,<assignment><start_tm>123456789575</start_tm><req_tm>1234568789854</req_tm><req>cn=FakeAdmin,ou=Admin,ou=ESC,o=authorizationpathfake</req><req_desc>Import - Child Request</req_desc></assignment>|'),
    (3, 'cn=TestingApp3,cn=Application,cn=Base,cn=Level2,cn=Definitions,cn=Configuration,cn=Drivers,cn=UserApplication,cn=FakePath,<assignment><start_tm>123456789575</start_tm><req_tm>1234568789854</req_tm><req>cn=FakeAdmin,ou=Admin,ou=ESC,o=authorizationpathfake</req><req_desc>Import - Child Request</req_desc></assignment>|cn=RoleTest3,cn=Application,cn=Base,cn=Level2,cn=Definitions,cn=Configuration,cn=Drivers,cn=UserApplication,cn=FakePath,<assignment><start_tm>123456789575</start_tm><req_tm>1234568789854</req_tm><req>cn=FakeAdmin,ou=Admin,ou=ESC,o=authorizationpathfake</req><req_desc>Import - Child Request</req_desc></assignment>'),
    (4, 'cn=RoleTest1,cn=Application,cn=Base,cn=Level2,cn=Definitions,cn=Configuration,cn=Drivers,cn=UserApplication,cn=FakePath,<assignment><start_tm>123456789575</start_tm><req_tm>1234568789854</req_tm><req>cn=FakeAdmin,ou=Admin,ou=ESC,o=authorizationpathfake</req><req_desc>Import - Child Request</req_desc></assignment>|cn=RoleTest5,cn=Application,cn=Base,cn=Level2,cn=Definitions,cn=Configuration,cn=Drivers,cn=UserApplication,cn=FakePath,<assignment><start_tm>123456789575</start_tm><req_tm>1234568789854</req_tm><req>cn=FakeAdmin,ou=Admin,ou=ESC,o=authorizationpathfake</req><req_desc>Import - Child Request</req_desc></assignment>')

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @TempUserObjects

--Splitter Statement
SELECT
    tuo.UserID,
    SUBSTRING('|' + tuo.AssignedRoles + '|', ct.UserID + 1, CHARINDEX('|', '|' + tuo.AssignedRoles + '|', ct.UserID + 1) - ct.UserID - 1) AS 'NRFAssignedRoles'
INTO
    #RolesStage2
FROM 
    @CountTable ct
CROSS JOIN
    @TempUserObjects tuo
WHERE
    ct.UserID < LEN('|' + tuo.AssignedRoles + '|')
    AND SUBSTRING('|' + tuo.AssignedRoles + '|', ct.UserID, 1) = '|'

--Shows SubstringCharindex works
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(AssignedRoles, 4, CHARINDEX(',', AssignedRoles) - 4) AS 'SubstringCharindex'
FROM
    @TempUserObjects

SELECT *
FROM #RolesStage2
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: Can you explain what is your issue and what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: what should be expected output?

Comment: I apologize. I am wanting to split each role in the string data up and join it back to the user ID. So the end query / table will be use ID - Assigned Role... however it should show duplicate User ID records for users who have multiple roles. You can see the string data, some users have 1 role some have multiple.

Comment: ALL - I think I figured out my major flaw.. My counter table did not have more than what I was splitting and cross joining back to.  (face to palm).